# How to receive Contact changes : Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to implement a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen if contact has been deleted/ updated. I read about `ContantObserver` but I have no idea how to run this in application background, like `BroadcastReceiver`.

How can I implement this? Is there any way to run `ContantObserver` in background of an application.

I followed [this FAQ.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401280/how-to-listen-for-changes-in-contact-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement a broadcaste Receiver and send Broadcaste in the `onChange` method of `ContentObserver` targetting this receiver.. see [this](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/custom-intents-and-broadcasting-with-receivers/) for using custom intents and broadcastes..

Comment: My need is to implement this functionality from background of an application. I mean my application is not on foreground and if contact has been changed, it must be listen by my application. I think ContentObserver needs to be run on foreground. Am I right?

Comment: @AndroidLearner .. thats why i suggested receiver which runs in background.. and Content Observer don't have to be in  foreground..

Answer (score 0):

Start a service and register the ContentObserver to this server

Here is a sample code I did which will listen to any changes in the Contacts.CONTENT_URI and notify the user

This is the service

```
public class ContactObserverService extends Service implements ContactObserver.OnUpdate {
private ContactObserver contactObserver ;

public ContactObserverService() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    contactObserver = new ContactObserver(this);
    Toast.makeText(this,"Service Started",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    this.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,false,contactObserver);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if( contactObserver !=null  )
    {
        this.getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(contactObserver);
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // The service is starting, due to a call to startService()
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Uri uri) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Contact Update Notifier")
            .setContentText(uri.getQuery())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.images);
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(1,builder.build());
}
}
```

The ContentObserver class is

```
public class ContactObserver extends ContentObserver {
private OnUpdate onUpdate;

public interface OnUpdate{
    void onUpdate(Uri uri);
}
public ContactObserver(OnUpdate onUpdate) {
    super(new Handler());
    this.onUpdate = onUpdate;
}

@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
    this.onChange(selfChange, null);
}
@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
    // this is NOT UI thread, this is a BACKGROUND thread
    uri.getQueryParameterNames();
    onUpdate.onUpdate(uri);
}
}
```