# Sync Android contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am making an app that fetch all contacts and save it my db which is working perfectly.

Now whenever user do **CRUD** operation in native i want that to be observed by my app so that i can update in my db too. *So after lot of research i found there is no way to know which particular contact has been updated or deleted.*

So i compared the **CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP** of contact with my sync time.

Now the issue am facing is with **Google sync** that runs every 20 minutes and update all contacts **CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP.** It makes me to update all those contacts

Is there any other possible way to achieve syncing (to get particular contact that has been updated). Tried Sync adapter, tells only change in URI not particular contact.

Any help or lead will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I had to maintain a list of my own in my application's database to keep track of any change in my native contacts

Comment: i cant compare every time to get the changes. As app need to be updated every second

Comment: You can see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431881/how-to-know-which-specific-contact-was-updated-in-android

Comment: this is not what i asked for. Even the version is being updated

Comment: Why don't you try BroadCast Receiver to get broadcast message about contact Update , add or delete? Or ContentObserver ?

Comment: there is no event for contact update or delete etc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431881/how-to-know-which-specific-contact-was-updated-in-android

Comment: http://www.grokkingandroid.com/use-contentobserver-to-listen-to-changes/

Comment: same issue with this too buddy .. no exact URI

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to keep a local copy of contacts db only needed information like **id** and **version**.

Here '**version**' is an interesting column which is increased everytime there is a change in the contact. so you can use this to find out exactly which one is changed.