# Receive Intent when contacts changed

Tags: android, android-intent, contacts

my app uses the contacts of the android device. For better performance the contacts are put into a cache. At the moment i refresh the cache after X minutes, in my eyes no perfect solution. Is there any way to receive an Intent via BroadcastReceiver when there is any change (create update delete) on the contact database?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot receive an intent after a contact was changed. It is impossible because the framework doesn't send any intents for these events. You can get an intent for when a user requests to add a contact; e.g., when a user clicks "+" button in the contacts app. But as I understand that is not what you need.

The only way I know to get notified when a new contact is added, is to [register a content observer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#registerContentObserver(android.net.Uri,%20boolean,%20android.database.ContentObserver)). You will probably want to create a background service that registers itself as a content observer.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401280/how-to-listen-for-changes-in-contact-database) is a helpful question discussing content observers.