# Event for add/edit/delete Contact in android

Tags: java, android

Is there any event for add/edit/delete in Contact List?

Comment: I don't think this can be "tried".

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401280/how-to-listen-for-changes-in-contact-database  (answered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are welcome to register a `ContentObserver` with an appropriate `Uri` from the `ContactsContract` `ContentProvider` to find out about changes to that `Uri`.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Any example for the same?

Comment: @AtulOHolic: None from me, and I have not gone looking for any.

Answer (score 0):

```
//initially all your contact is stored in database then use this service and regiter this service in manifest 
public class ContactSync_Service extends IntentService {

public ContactSync_Service() {
    super("intent service");

}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    MyContentObserver contentObserver = new MyContentObserver();
    this.getApplicationContext()
            .getContentResolver()
            .registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                    true, contentObserver);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();

}

class MyContentObserver extends ContentObserver {

    public MyContentObserver() {
        super(null);
    }

//whenever a contact is add,modified,delete this method will get called
    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        Log.e("changes", "changes");

        syncDatabase();
        super.onChange(selfChange);
    }

}



//comparing database contact list with phone's contact list if there is contact is added or modified
@TargetApi(18)
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public void syncDatabase() {

    ContactDatabase db = new ContactDatabase(this);
//get all the data from database include contact and name
//contact bean is a class containing setter and getter of getName() and getContact()
    ArrayList<ContactBean> arrayListDataase = db.fetch();
    int size = arrayListDataase.size();
    Log.e("size of arraylist", size + "");
    /*
     * ArrayList<String> arrayListContact=new ArrayList<String>();
     * 
     * 
     * for(int i=0;i<arrayListDataase.size();i++) {
     * arrayListContact.add(arrayListDataase.get(i).getContact()); }
     */

    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
            null, null);
    int i = 0;

    if (phones.moveToFirst()) {

        do {

            boolean flag = false;

            String phoneNumber = phones
                    .getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

            // Log.e("number", phoneNumber);


            for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {

                //comparing  database contact number with phone's contact list contact number 
                if (arrayListDataase.get(i).getContact().equalsIgnoreCase(phoneNumber)) 
                {   

                    flag = true;

                    String nameFromContactList = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String nameFromDatabase=arrayListDataase.get(i).getName();


                    //check if name is changed in contact list
                    if(!nameFromContactList.equalsIgnoreCase(nameFromDatabase))
                    {
                        db.upDateNameWhenChangeInContactListOfPhone(nameFromContactList, phoneNumber);

                    }


                    break;      

                }

            }

            if (!flag) {

                String image_uri="";
                Log.e("contact changed", phoneNumber);
                String name = phones
                        .getString(phones
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String email = phones
                        .getString(phones
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                String time_stamp = phones
                        .getString(phones
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP));




                image_uri = phones
                          .getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));


                if((image_uri==null) || image_uri.matches("")  )
                {
                    image_uri="";
                }



                db.insert(name, phoneNumber, email, image_uri);
                //break;

            }



        } while (phones.moveToNext());

        phones.close();

    }

}}
```