# Broadcast Receiver for insertion into contacts

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-contacts

I am trying to launch an application after successful saving of contact in  androids in built contact Phone book. so I want to know ,is there any Broadcast Receiver for updation in phonebook and addition of new contact in phonebook.

Or any other way to find the event of addition or updation in phonebook.

Comment: check out my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29031605/1881527 it may help you...:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to implement an Android Service and register an observer to the list of Contact, you can refer to this question to receive change event on the phonebook[Contact Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401280/how-to-listen-for-changes-in-contact-database).
After that you can start you application. You can make your service run on device restart by using brodcast receiver for boot.

Comment: Observer only use when application running, how to know when application is closed, I don't want to continuously running background service. Is Can i create Broadcast for that.