# Launching an activity after when a user create/edit a contact in android

Tags: android, android-activity, contacts

I would like to learn how can i launch an activity after phone user edit/create a contact.
This activity shouldn't launched when a contact is updated automatically from other accounts like google, facebook. Also, I need to get contact's infos(like name, phone number) and i would like to do it for android 2.3.3 and later versions.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this would help you    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401280/how-to-listen-for-changes-in-contact-database

Comment: Thank you for reply. I think it is only about listening contact changes. I need to have a method that gives contact info and listener should work for only manual changes.