# Is there a Way to Get the Contacts Changes in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-contacts, android-4.4-kitkat

I am creating an App in which in a part i have to regularly check contacts. But It would be nice if I get Notify, Whenever any Contact Get Added, Deleted or Updated in the Contacts Database of Android or Any Contact Event Occurs. Is there a way to do that and Can i get those Changes?

```
Even if i don't get those changes its still OK but i wanna get notify that something has changed in Contact Database.

I tried but don't find any solution.
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement a **BroadCastReceiver** and send Broadcast in the `onChange` method of **ContentObserver** targeting this receiver.

Extend **ContentObserver** class

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401280/how-to-listen-for-changes-in-contact-database) for more

Comment: OK i try to implement that.