# How i can implement Android Broadcast intent on any contact add or change?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

Is there any standard broadcast intent that I can register a BroadcastReceiver for that gets triggered whenever a contact is added or changed? I've been looking through the docs for a while now but haven't found anything. Maybe it's hidden somewhere deep and one of you guys knows where.

Comment: hmm im not sure but you could always just save the last time you synced with contacts, and then every time they open the app you could query contacts for all that were created after your last sync, then update your sync date

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to listen for changes in Contact Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401280/how-to-listen-for-changes-in-contact-database)