# Android SQLite adding contacts 'dynamically'

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contacts

In my Android app, an Activity performs a query to get the contacts on the phone and stores them into a sqlite database. For now, this is performed only once during the first launch of the Activity because that operation takes about two seconds to execute (which is actually a lot of time)

However that workaround comes with an issue: if the phone user adds some contact my app will never be able to get them. Then, I was wondering if it was possible for my app to ´listen ´ for that event and add the contact in the database when it occurs.

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Did you try to check if the count of the contacts in the contact list is changed and if it is changed - add the last added into your db?

Comment: check this link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401280/how-to-listen-for-changes-in-contact-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using [ContentObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html).

You have to simply

- Implement a subclass of `ContentObserver`
- you have to register your ContentObserver to listen the change.

For more detail how to do it you can follow this article [Use Android’s ContentObserver in Your Code to Listen to Data Changes](https://www.grokkingandroid.com/use-contentobserver-to-listen-to-changes/)

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I need. I read the article you provided but can you just tell me if the Observer will notice a change even if the application isn't running during that change?

Comment: No the life cycle of content observer ends when your application is not running. So it cannot listen to change if your application is closed.

Comment: That´s quite unfortunate then, an app is not supposed to be opened forever. Is there any workaround or other solution for this?