# Monitoring phone contact changes in Android

Tags: android

I am creating an Android application which makes use of the Contact-contract to get the phone contact list.

So whenever changes occur in phone contact list, my app's contact list needs to be updated. For this how to know the changes of phone contact when my app starts, and get the changed contact's details?

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this post

[how to listen for changes in Contact Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401280/how-to-listen-for-changes-in-contact-database)

i hope this will helps you