# Updating the contact details on a messaging app

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to develop some kind of messaging app. Each time I receive a message, I saved it along with the message sender and message body to an SQLite Database.

Here's the the flow,

1. I received a message from a certain number
2. Check if that number exist in my phone's contacts
3. Saved the message on my DB with the following fields, contact_name, message_body

Problem now is when that certain contact updates it's name outside my app, how can I track or tell my app to update that name on the DB inside my app.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to implement your own ContentObserver and whenever there will be any updates to device contact your ContentObserver will be notified. Take a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401280/how-to-listen-for-changes-in-contact-database

Answer (score 0):

You Need to Store Contact Details in Some Cloud Server,then Every Users Information will be stored in that Server and fetch that list and compare with Local SqlLite DB and Update the Local Database based on Changes in Server at Regular Interval of time using Service.so if a User changes his Name Outside,that will be Reflected in Server and By Service to CheckContacts will Update it in Local.

i'd Suggest to Use Parse Cloud Server for this,it has SDK Built in for Android,Download and include it in your libs and your are good to go
https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide