# Best method to implement Android client-server communication with realtime local notification

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sql-server, localnotification

I am creating an app where user data should be saved in my database. When a user submit certain data like "name" "personal note" I need to get a real time notification from my MySQL database. How do I implement this?

Comment: did you try anything yet?

Comment: Yes .. Someone suggested using jquery for local notification from db.. But am fairly new to this. I couldn't implement it.

Comment: Maybe you should learn some basics first before implementing this. What you need is a ContentObserver. See this post for some sample code to listen to database changes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401280/how-to-listen-for-changes-in-contact-database

Comment: Thanks a lot... I will refer that for now.

Comment: I am using only external database. I need a notification on my pc.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to create a notification from the submission, rather that from the database.

Which User on which database ? Who is client, who is server ?

Comment: Android app is the client .. It's a simple app where can can submit "name" "phone Number" .. Am hosting a MySQL server where the data should be stored from the Android application. I will have a php script on the server which will receive the data from Android app and store it in database. I need to refresh the db every time to see if I received any data..I want to get a notification every time user submit data from the app. That's what am looking to implement.