# Observer for Sugar Orm

Tags: java, android, observers, sugarorm

I need to use an observer that is called when my `database` was modified. This exists natively with `Android cursor`.

It is a `LoaderCallback`.

How can I use this with `SugarOrm`? Does anyone have any examples?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401280/how-to-listen-for-changes-in-contact-database

Comment: did you found a solution to this?